# Is it possible to add row dynamically to panelgrid(outputlabel, inputtext) in PrimeFaces/JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datagrid

I have a `<p:panelGrid>` like this:

```
<p:panelGrid style="margin:inherit !important; width: 100%;
             display: flex !important;"
             styleClass="new_player_panel">

    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel value="Name in passport: " />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText id="nameInPassport"
                         value="#{firstPlayerLoginManagedBean.surnameInPassport}"
                         required="true">
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:message for="nameInPassport" display="icon" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:outputLabel value="Firstname in passport:" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText id="firstnameInPassport" label="Utazási"
                         value="#{firstPlayerLoginManagedBean.firstnameInPassport}"
                         required="true">
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:message for="firstnameInPassport" display="icon" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

and so on.

I tried to create this with `dataGrid(managedbean, inputfields in lists)`, but `<p:dataGrid>` is not the perfect way to do my task exactly.  I want to get behavior like this: If I click the plus icon next to the nationality field then creates another `<p:inputText>` for my second nationality and the other part of the form stay in the same state, and the new field push down the other fields. I have to use it a lot parts of my application. thanks in advance.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: You are showing a `<p:panelGrid>` in the given XHTML code snippet but the text implies a `<p:dataGrid>` instead. The title also somewhat contradicts the question body. This is more likely related to *conditional rendering* of components rather than *adding components themselves dynamically*.

Comment: I just want to illustrate how it should work, and printscreen the test datagrid. The panelgrid uses a row and columns to show the outputtext-inputtext pairs. I tried it with rendered attribute, but it not renders in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ui:repeat>` to achieve this functionality, this is how you can achieve this functionality:

*.xhtml page, you build nationality field dynamically after you press "Add Nationality" button.

```
<h:outputPanel id="nationality_container">
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.passport.nationalities}" var="nationality">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bean.getNationalyLabel(nationality)}"
    <h:inputText value="#{nationality}"/>
</ui:repeat>
</h:outputPanel>

<h:commandButton value="Add Nationality" listener="#{bean.addNationality}" update="nationality_container"/>
```

Backing Bean:

```
public Bean{
private Passport passport;

//adding new nationality and set its index
public void addNationality(){ //adding new nationality and set its index
    passport.getNationalities.add(new Nationality(passport.getNationalities.size()));
}

//this method return you appropriate label, for id = 1 it's "First Nationality", and so on
public String getNationalityLabel(Nationality nationality){
   if(nationality.id == 1){
        return "Nationality";
   }else if(nationality.id == 2){
        return "Second nationality";
   }
   ...
}
```

}

Object passport which encapsulates `List<Nationality> nationalities;`

```
public Passport{
    ...
    private List<Nationality> nationalities;
    ...
}
```

Object `Nationality` with parameter `index` to store its index, first, second, third.

```
public Nationality{
    int index; //1,2,3... first, second, third nationality, etc...
    String nationality;
    public Nationality(int index){
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Of course you can find a more elegant solution for your task, but using `<ui:repeat>` tag is required.

**Pay attention that I didn't test this code, this is only general idea how this functionality should be implemented.**

Comment: You're mixing `<ui:param>` with `<ui:repeat>`.